# Read more Read less stuck in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How do I make sure that the class for each notification does not change when I press the ..., I want to implement read more read less in angular for given notifications, and with this, if I press the button all the notifications get opened.

```html
<div class="notificationList" *ngFor="let a of alertsList">
    <div [ngClass]="{'showLess': more}" [innerHTML]="a.Message"></div>
    <a class="readMore" (click)="more==!more">...</a>
</div>
```

```js
public alertsList: any = [
    {
        "Message": "<p>hi hello</p><p>dsaddddsdad ad s sdaf asf sf sd sd fsa ff sdf af s fsa f sadf sa faf sadf a a fa</p>",
    },

    {
        "Message": "<p>hi hello</p><p>dsaddadsaddd ad s sdaf asf sf sd sd fsa ff sdf af s fsa f sadf sa faf sadf a a fa</p>",
    },

    {
        "Message": "<p>hi hello</p><p>dsadddd ad gfgdgfds sdaf asf sf sd sd fsa ff sdf af s fsa f sadf sa faf sadf a a fa</p>",
    },

    {
        "Message": "<p>hi hello</p><p>dsadddd ad s sdadfgfdgf asf sf sd sd fsa ff sdf af s fsa f sadf sa faf sadf a a fa</p>",
    }
];
```

Using this dummy data to check, as I will be receiving data from the server in this manner only

I am a new developer so please bare with me, i used this method below and it worked can you please tell me if its the best practice or not?

```html
<div class="notificationList" *ngFor="let a of alertsList; index as i">
    <div [ngClass]="{'showMore': more[i], 'showLess': !more[i]}" [innerHTML]=" a.Message">
    </div>
    <a class="readMore" (click)="more[i]=!more[i]">...</a>
</div>
```

Comment: you have to make more an element of the alert: a.more, as @MichealD did it

Comment: the problem might be that the `more` variable is not associated with one notification. Also check your `(click)="more == !more"`. Are you trying to reassign more or comparing it? To reassign `more` use single `=`, `==` is comparing it

Comment: Yes corrected that more=!more
how do i assign it to one notification

Answer (score 4):

If you use a single central variable to control the show/hide feature, then it'd naturally affect all the places it's used in.

You have to introduce an additional property in each object of the `altersList` array to individually adjust each object's state.

**Controller (*.ts)**

```js
// assuming `alertsList` is initialized in a subscription

this.someService.getAlerts().pipe(
  map((alerts: any) =>
    alerts.map(alert => ({ ...alert, more: true }))
  )
).subscribe((alerts: any) => 
  this.alertsList = alerts
);
```

**Template (*.html)**

```html
<div  class="notificationList" *ngFor="let a of alertsList">
  <div [ngClass]="{'showLess': a.more}" [innerHTML]="a.Message" ></div>
  <a class="readMore" (click)="a.more=!a.more">...</a>
</div>
```

#### Update

If you're using mock data from a service, you could still use the same [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to include an additional property to the object. Just ignore the `subscribe` part for now.

**Component**

```js
this.alertsList = this.someService.alertsList.map(
  alerts.map(alert => ({ ...alert, more: true }))
);
```

Comment: Its a service which is coming in form of array:-
notifitcations :{
"message":"xyz"
}

Comment: Is there an option where we can use index as i to solve this?

Comment: @RahulJain: Sorry I don't quite understand your comment. If you have trouble with the `alerts.map` that I've written above, please post the part of the `alertsList` initialization in the question. Then we could see how it could be adjusted.

Comment: I will try your method, can you please check if what i did is a good practice or not?

Comment: @RahulJain: Using index assumes there is a `more` array in the component controller. Something like `this.more = this.alertsList.map(() => false)` after the `this.alertsList` initialization. IMO using an additional property in each object would be cleaner.